# How to add list to values of Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, format

I am writing a script that detects the methods of a file.
Keys are function names and values are holding its path, row,column in this format :

```
[path,row,column]
```

Same function might be occur in a different locations(same file or a different file)

So I am checking this case: If we have same function, then we add  new values corresponding to its key.

```
if methodDictionary.get(functionName) is None:
    methodDictionary[functionName] =[path,row,column]
elif [path,row,column]  not in methodDictionary[functionName]:                                                                                                                                                             
    methodDictionary[functionName] =[methodDictionary.get(functionName)]                                                     
    methodDictionary[functionName].append([path,row,column])
```

I think that the problem occurs in elif statement. It can't checks whether key has same value or not. Bu I can't fix that. Also there is a formatting problem can be seen from output.

I want a format like this;

```
{'int a(int x)' : [[path1,row1,column1],[path2,row2,column2]]}
```

How can I do that?

The output of code :

```
f()': [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[['a.cpp', '3', '3'], ['a.cpp', '8', '3']], ['a.cpp', '13', '3']], ['a.cpp', '3', '3']], ['a.cpp', '8', '3']], ['a.cpp', '13', '3']], ['a.cpp', '3', '3']], ['a.cpp', '8', '3']], ['a.cpp', '13', '3']], ['a.cpp', '3', '3']], ['a.cpp', '8', '3']], ['a.cpp', '13', '3']], ['a.cpp', '3', '3']], ['a.cpp', '8', '3']], ['a.cpp', '13', '3']], ['a.cpp', '3', '3']], ['a.cpp', '8', '3']], ['a.cpp', '13', '3']]
```

Comment: ```{'int a(int x)' : [path,row,column],[path,row,column]}``` is invalid. You cannot have "synonyms" for a python dictionary. Only 1 value per key

Comment: ah yes, I edited @Sujay

Comment: replace elif with else. Add the check if the list is the list is already appended in the body of the else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code, the problem may lie here:

```
methodDictionary[functionName] =[methodDictionary.get(functionName)]
```

You are updating the key every time the `elif` block is executed. Instead try doing:

```
if methodDictionary.get(functionName) is None:
    methodDictionary[functionName] =[[path,row,column]]
else:                                                    
    methodDictionary[functionName].append([path,row,column])
```

Comment: I tried and this is the output
` 'int f()': ['a.cpp', '3', '3', ['a.cpp', '8', '3'], ['a.cpp', '13', '3'], ['a.cpp', '3', '3']], `

Comment: @HAZAN check the answer now?